# Jsoup response not like browser inspect

Tags: spring, reactjs, jsoup

I want parse a web page with jsoup. But its html returned is not like browser inspect. When I go to web page from browser, I can see `<ol>` tags under `<section id='js_item_list_section'>......</section>`. But if I call web page with jsoup in spring boot project, I can't see `<ol>` tags under that section. There is another `<div key="">` under section. Returned responses below:

JSOUP Response:

```html
<section id="js_item_list_section" class="item-list item-list--loading clearfix">
 <div key="itemlist-loader" class="ellipsis-loader-wrapper ellipsis-loader-wrapper--text ellipsis-loader-wrapper--top">
  <div class="ellipsis-loader ellipsis-loader--branded center-x">
   <div class="ellipsis-loader__dot"></div>
   <div class="ellipsis-loader__dot"></div>
   <div class="ellipsis-loader__dot"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="loader-text center-x">Y&uuml;kleniyor</span>
 </div>
</section>
```

Web browser (Chrome) Inspector:

```html
<section id="js_item_list_section" class="item-list clearfix">
  <ol>
     <li>.....</li>
     <li>.....</li>
  <ol>
</section>
```

I think it is about React.js.

Also my code block here:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.connect(myUrl)
  .ignoreContentType(true)
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36")
  .get();
Element itemListSection  = document.getElementById("js_item_list_section");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that the page you are trying to parse contains dynamically generated content (js_item_list_section already hints towards JavaScript being used to render this)

JSoup does not interpret JavaScript and therefore will also not load content that is accessed via AJAX calls. So JSoup can't be used the way you want it unfortunately.

I see you have two options:

1) Use a tool like selenium web driver, which controls a real browser from Java, allowing to also parse dynamically generated content. This is easy to achieve, but introduces new dependencies (a whole browser!) and runs rather slow.

2) Analyze the AJAX calls that load the content that the JavaScript uses to render the page. Find the actual calls using the browser's developer tools. Then call this directly from within Java and parse that data. Often such data is transmitted in JSON format, so Jsoup is only of limited help here. This option takes more effort, but runs faster and does not add more heavy dependencies to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried web driver. But I can not get page source this time. Because when initialized new driver, chrome browser opened in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I tried web driver like that:

```
System.setProperty(MyChromeExePath);
        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.get(trivagoUrl.toString());
        String pageSource = webDriver.getPageSource();
```

After this line `WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();`, browser opened. After that it throw time exception error

```
2018-08-24 18:52:01.116[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m29316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RP0T36G', ip: '192.168.1.21', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver] with root cause

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:148) ~[guava-23.6-jre.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.io.zizu.m2m.parse.command.TrivagoSearchCommand.getSearchResults(TrivagoSearchCommand.java:131) ~[main/:na]
    at com.io.zizu.m2m.parse.command.TrivagoSearchCommand$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a6dcf772.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```